# make some columns unsortable?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Des anyone know how I can make certain columns unsortable for this [Jquery plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)? I cannot seem to find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've missed it, here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object 
        headers: { 
            // assign the secound column (we start counting zero) 
            1: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            // assign the third column (we start counting zero) 
            2: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

[unsortable columns](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use the [headers](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html) option to make certain columns un-sortable.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object 
        headers: { 
            // assign the secound column (we start counting zero) 
            1: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            // assign the third column (we start counting zero) 
            2: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It certainly did dSquared :)!

Answer (score 2):

It's right there under the `headers` option in the big table on the page you linked to:

> An object of instructions for per-column controls in the format:
>   `headers: { 0: { option: setting }, ... }` **For example, to disable
>   sorting on the first two columns of a table: `headers: { 0: { sorter:
>   false}, 1: {sorter: false} }`**